# How to replace a comma with an underscore in Django template filter

Tags: javascript, python, django

Hi I have javascript as follows contains django variables.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.item }}_{{ a.kidu|slice:":2" }}').html('<a class="a1" href="{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}">{{ a.id }}</a>');
            $('#{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.item}}_{{ a.kidu|slice:":2" }}').addClass('{{ a.state__name.split|join:"_" }}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

all results are a query result fro my view:

```
context['all_results'] = m.values('set', 'kidu', 'id', 'item', 'state__name')
```

The problem am facing is if the value of item is a comma separated value, then the id is not passing to the template I have. But if the value of item is a one word my code is working perfectly and the id is passing to the template. Any idea guys?

Comment: So am planning to add a djnago filter to replace the comma with an underscore. I manually changed the value in DB to test whether its working. Observed its working well when i replace it with underscore.

Comment: why you do not use custom filters?

Comment: ya..  I tried that. It didnt

Comment: `{% for l in all_items
                                    <td style="text-align: center"
                                        id="{{m.set|slice:':7' }}_{{m.item}}_{{l}}">
                                    </td>
                        {% endfor %}` This is where am using those javascript ids in my template. Both must be matched right

Comment: the above code, that you have shared is in your js. So you can use js 'replace' method.

Comment: Yes Hassan, but how can I do that in my corresponding django template where am passing those ids

Comment: So {{m.set|slice:':7' }} and {{m.item}} have commas in them?

Comment: Instead of having us guess what the model looks like, can you include the relevant model file. As well as what you have tried so far

Comment: set slice dont have any commas. Am just getting onlythe first 7 characters from set. But item have commas (Ex: item = sasi,kuttan)

Comment: Its a very complex and long models Sayse. The problem is just I want to replace the commas with underscore using any django filters..

Comment: Simple solution will be custom filter. It will be used like this {{m.item|replace_commas}}. Is this not working?

Comment: In replace_commas filter, you will replace all commas with underscore.

Comment: `Invalid filter: 'replace_commas'` got this error. You mean template tags?

Comment: Yes. This is not builtin filter. You have to add it in your custom tags or filters.

Comment: Its an old version of Django Hassan

Comment: M Hassan means write your own... you don't need to include the whole model, just the relevant parts.

Comment: Oh thats an another option also. Was just curious whether there is an in built filter for that

Comment: @vellattukudy what do you mean by comma separated ? is item a list??

Comment: No raj. Its a field in my DB. The value inside is comma separated one instead of just a normal word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In file where you have you custom filters and tags, add following function

```
 from django import template
 register = template.Library()

 @register.filter
 def replace_commas(string):
    return string.replace(',', '_')
```

For view how to create custom filters, view this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) of django.

1. Create a folder 'templatetags' in your app directory
2. Create a file name 'my_filter.py' and `'__init__.py'` in that folder
3. Copy above code in my_filter.py
4. In you template, add {% load my_filter %} at the top.
5. Now you can use your filter like this {{m.item|replace_commas}}

Note, you could make the template tag a little more flexible by making the find/replace an argument. e.g.:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def find_replace(string, find_replace=",|_"):
    find, replace = find_replace.split("|")
    return string.replace(',', '_')
```

Then you would be able to use it like so in your template:

```
{{ m.item|find_replace:",|-" }}
```

(would replace `,`'s with `-`'s

Comment: `context['all_results'] = m.values('set', 'kidu', 'id', 'item', 'state__name')` Am passing the item from my view as above. The method isnt working Hassan

Comment: what is m? is it a query result?

Comment: how did you add custom filter/tag? did you follow same way as described in documentation that I have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Because nothing to do with that righ since I have the query and I will be passing those values in my template and JS

Comment: Thanks a lot Hassan. Worked!!

Comment: Just a small doubt, what if the item have comma and space together? Like instead of one comma (kuttu,sasi,sambhu) there is a space after the comma (kuttu, sasi, sambhu)?

Comment: Found the way. Just add one more filter like above for space replacement. Thaks Hassan. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a property on your model to do the replace then use this property in the template

```
# model
@property
def uncommad_item(self)
    return self.item.replace(',', '_')

# template
{{ a.uncommad_item }}
```

Comment: context['all_results'] = m.values('set', 'kidu', 'id', 'item', 'state__name') Am passing the item from my view as above. The method isnt working Sayse

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code in your question.

Comment: `<td style="text-align: center" id="XX_yy,CPI_RC">
                                    </td>` This how my code looks like when I inspect element in chrome. I want to remove that comma with an underscore